# How to get filtered Django ORM query result in Django rest framework response

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My question is about getting Django query result in Django-rest-framework api's response. 
I have the following models of Product, Attribute and Productoptions in my Django project:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productid = models.AutoField(db_column='productId', primary_key=True)  
    productname = models.CharField(db_column='productName', max_length=200)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    attributeid = models.AutoField(db_column='attributeId', primary_key=True)
    attributename = models.CharField(db_column='attributeName', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) 

class Productoptions(models.Model):
    optionsid = models.AutoField(db_column='OptionsId', primary_key=True)
    optionproductid = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='optionProductId', blank=True, null=True)
    optionattributeid = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='optionAttributeId', blank=True, null=True)
```

I have filled sample data in all three tables and when trying to get the products whose attribute name is nike, the following Django query perfectly worked in Python shell.

```
Productoptions.objects.filter(optionattributeid__attributename='nike').values('optionproductid__productname')
```

Get the result

```
<QuerySet [{'optionproductid__productname': 'nike shirt'}, {'optionproductid__productname': 'nike tracksuit'}]>
```

But the related model class query is not working in my view

```
class ProductOptionsView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProductOptionsSerializer

    def get(self,request):
        queryset = Productoptions.objects.filter(optionattributeid__attributename='nike').values('optionproductid__productname')

        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am not getting the desired result from this view. Is there any way that all Django query will simply provide result with Django-rest-framework. All get and post queries are perfectly working in Python shell.

Is there any other way or DRF has its own method for it to use nested models result in rest api. I have read Django Filter too but it has lack of documnetaion in Django's website.

Comment: `queryset` is undefined in ur example

Comment: I have edited the questions the variable name was queryset.

Comment: Try removing `.values` part at the end, so that you pass Django models instead of python dicts to serializer, then adjust the output in serializer as needed

Comment: Now the output only gets data from Productoptions table.

Comment: yep, now edit serializer so that it outputs what you need

Comment: 1. Don't repeat the name of the model class in the attributes - use just `name` not `productname`. 2. Use singular nouns for model class names - `Productoption` instead of `Productoptions`. 3. a) If there are no extra fields in `Productoptions`, create a `ManyToManyField` on `Product` (or `Attribute`) and remove that class. b) If there are extra fields, specify `Productoption` as `through` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on what @CrowbarKZ said in the comments, first remove the `.values` at the end of the queryset, the input of the serializer needs to be a queryset, and not a dict. If you want to have `Product` and `Attribute` fields in your `ProductoptionSerializer`, you need those serializers too, as described in the doc : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (productid, productname)

class AttributeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attribute          
        fields = (attributeid, attributename)

class ProductoptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    optionproductid = ProductSerializer()
    optionattributeid = AttributeSerializer()
    optionsid = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:        
        model = Productoption
        fields = (optionproductid, optionattributeid, optionsid)
```